# Adding items to an existing dictionary using loops in python

Tags: python

I want the output to be in the form:

```
dic = {size1:file/path1, size2:file/path2}
```

But what I am getting in individual dictionaries for each combination, like:

```
{size1:file/path1}
{size2:file/path2, size1:file/path1, ...}
```

This is the code I came up with, can anyone correct my code.

```
import os, subprocess, re, sys
records = {}
out = sys.stdout
with open('PythonFilesInMac.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     sys.stdout = outfile
     for cdir, dir, files in os.walk(r'/Users'):
         for file in files:
             if file.endswith('.py'):
                filename = os.path.join(cdir, file)
                size = os.path.getsize(filename)
                records[size] = filename #records = {size:filename}
                print records             #how do I use dict.update() here?   
     sys.stdout = out
```

Comment: You are getting all of the combinations because you are printing out `records` in every loop.

Comment: You can print after loop end.

Comment: your code seems correct, do a `print records` after your loop to check that it is indeed correct

Comment: what will result when size of two or more files are same ?

Comment: if two files have the same size, this code will silently overwrite the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two problems in your code. the first is you should put print outside your loop. the second is there may be two files with same size, better to put them in a list.

```
import os, subprocess, re, sys
records = {}
out = sys.stdout
with open('PythonFilesInMac.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     sys.stdout = outfile
     for cdir, dir, files in os.walk(r'/Users'):
         for file in files:
             if file.endswith('.py'):
                filename = os.path.join(cdir, file)
                size = os.path.getsize(filename)
                records.setdefault(size, []).append(filename)
     print records  
     sys.stdout = out
```